# "your account has been scheduled for removal" and it's still there

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I've requested the removal of one of my accounts on SE.

I've received the mail "your accout has been scheduled for removal (...) your accout will be automatically deleted within 24 hours".

However, 3 days has passed, and that account is still on my account list.

Have I done or understood anything wrong?

Comment: I fear the message is misleading. High rep accounts do not get deleted automatically, it's a manual process done by the team, e.g. preserving all your votes. So it takes a while, you can try emailing the team directly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard there's no need to, if I know this process is manual. However, the mail said it will be automatically within 24 hours, so after that time I've thought "oops, something went wrong"

Comment: Sounds like a bug or misclick of the one handling your request, worth someone looking into it.